# Combinatorics/ asymptotic behaviour

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

You have a box with **n**  marbles and we want to pick **k** out of it and we do not take the order of the marbles into account. For **k** fixed let **m(n)** denote the possible combinations of the marbles that we take out of the box , show that $m(n) \in \mathcal{O}(n^k)$

So isn't this the very definition of the binomial coefficent? so m(n)= ${n}\choose{k}$ and we have to show that ${n}\choose{k}$ $\leq c*n^k$

I know that ${\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)}^{k}$ $\leq$ ${n}\choose{k}$ $\leq {\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)}^{k}$

but how can I prove ${n}\choose{k}$ $\leq c*n^k$?

edit: I can use the fact that
${n}\choose{k}$ = $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{1* 2* \dots *(n-k)*\dots*n}{k!(n-k)!}$ = $\frac{(n-k+1) *\dots*n}{k!} \leq \frac{n^k}{k!} \leq n^k$

would this suffice?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct :)

Comment: Thank you for looking at this:)